# MYSQL SELECT MAX(id) + 1 where id < 1000

Tags: mysql, delphi, auto-increment

I need to use something like:

```
 INSERT into tablename(id) 
     SELECT max(id) + 1 
     FROM tablename
```

where `id` is less than 1000 and `if max(id) = 1000 insert next id as 1`, so that the column fills from 1-1000 and start again.

I can have and autoincrement primary key column.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

I am not an SQL guru, but with the comments below I have done this in Delphi which is where this SQL will be executed. I would still like to know how to do it all in MYSQL and maybe one of the gurus here can help to round this off.

This is what I did:

```
procedure TForm11.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
lastserial : Integer;
begin
 with LastRowQuery do
  begin
    sql.Clear;
    sql.Add('SELECT autoid, id FROM inctest ORDER BY autoid DESC LIMIT 1;');
    execute;
  end;
  If  LastRowQueryid.value < 1000 then lastserial:=  LastRowQueryid.value + 1
  else
   lastserial := 1;
   with LastRowQuery do
    begin
     sql.Clear;
     sql.Add('Insert into inctest (id) values(:theserial)');
     ParamByName('theserial').Value := lastserial;
   execute;
 end;
end;
```

Comment: I don't think there's a tractible way to do this. You'd have to pick _the highest, most-duplicated ID_.

Comment: How about: `INSERT into inctest(id) 
SELECT TOP 1 id % 100 + 1 FROM inctest ORDER BY autoid DESC`

Comment: @kobik I think the syntax would be different in MYSQL.

Comment: I don't have MYSQL to test. if `top` does not work use `LIMIT 1` as you did. p.s. in your Delphi code, there is no need for `sql.Clear; sql.Add...`. simply use `sql.Text := ...`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think maybe you want this:
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/mathematical-functions.html#function_mod

Giving *something like*:

```
INSERT into tablename(id) SELECT MOD(count(id),1000)+1 FROM tablename
```

OR similarly,

```
INSERT into tablename(id) SELECT (count(id)%1000)+1 FROM tablename
```

Cheers.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. I tried this but after the max it starts adding 0.

Comment: I think `%` operator is standard in SQL and easier to read, imho

Comment: @user2242467, Please try to understand an answer rather than just copy and pasting. I think you want `select mod(max(id),1000)+1`

Comment: How about populating a table with 1000 rows and the updating the oldest one?

Comment: @user606723 thanks for the nudge, I am trying to understand SQL. I am a novice with SQL.

Comment: @'alar'cop I have tried what you sugested, once I get to the max number it reverts to 1 for every subsequent insertion. Earkier I had a similar thing but was getting subsequent insertions of the maximum value. The purpose of this is to generate a sequence of serial numbers and once the limit is reached revert to 1 again. I could simply archive the table and truncate it, but I was hoping to get a little more elegant!

Comment: Ok try now. Yes I agree - there _must_ always be a nicer way to do something like that.

Comment: @'alar'cop I have slept on itand I think I have a solution. This is going to be executed from a delphi application so I can use a query to: select max(id) if it is less than 1000 increase by one and if it equals 1000 insert 1 ........ It may be a few days, but I will post my code here which will be a combination of SQL and delphi, which may help someone else. Would still like to be able to do it all in a query though!

Comment: @'alar'cop and @user606723 I have pasted my delphi code above, This will work. I would like to see how this could be done in a SQL query or SQL command.

Comment: did you try it in SQL after I edited replacing 'max' with 'count'?

Comment: @d'alar'cop no I did not, I was probablly too tired to see it last night I will try now.

Comment: @d'alar'cop That works a treat! just one line of code and look at all my Delphi code to do the same thing. I would vote your elegant line up if I had the reputation to do so. Thanks a lot.

Comment: I'm glad for you - seriously. Anyway, since you are the asker, you may be able to 'tick the answer' as "correct"?

Comment: @d'alar'cop I am new here so have just ticked the answer. Appreicate the help.